# ¿Cómo defino dinámicamente una lista o cadena vacía?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando en una función que hace una serie de cosas y que, según un parámetro que reciba, devuelve una cadena o una lista vacía.

Más o menos:

```
def haz_cosas(numero, tipo_de_variable):
    if numero > 10:
       # Haz una serie de cosas y finalmente...
       return "Hola"

    # Si no, devuelve o bien una cadena vacía o bien una lista vacía
    # dependiendo de lo que diga `tipo_de_variable`
```

Así por ejemplo si lo llamo diciendo:

```
haz_cosas(0, str)
```

Querría que me devolviera `''` (cadena vacía). Es decir, lo que sería llamar a `str()`.

Y si la llamno con:

```
haz_cosas(0, list)
```

Que devuelva `[]` (lista vacía).

Lo mismo con diccionarios, set y demás.

Sé que para instanciar una clase dinámicamente se usa [`getattr(objeto, nombre)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), pero para `str` y `list` no sé cómo instanciarlos dinámicamente pues no sé exactamente de qué cuelga el objeto `str`.

También, esto no funciona:

```
>>> d = 'str'
>>> d()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: ¡Anda! Creo que sería tan fácil como decir `d = str; d()`... :/ Lo dejo por si hay algo más potente.

Comment: Efectivamente, en Python las "variables" son solo nombres o identificadores   asociados a  un objeto en memoria . `list`, `set`, `int`, etc no son nada especial, son variables globales del módulo asociados al objeto (clase/tipo de turno). Si se los pasas a tu función  el identificador `tipo_de_variable` pasa a estar asociado a la misma clase/tipo y puedes usarlo para  instanciarlo como comentas, `return tipo_de_variable()`. Claro,siempre que alguien no tuviera la brillante idea de reasignar a la variable otro objeto (`list = []`, `list = set`, `str = None`...) antes de llamar a tu función :).

Comment: @FJSevilla genial gracias por la confirmación! Si quieres ponlo como respuesta y así además de las gracias te puedo dar un +25 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de que no veo el objetivo de lo que quieres hacer (seguro que es por algo)
la solución la tienes a solo una linea:

```
def haz_cosas(numero, tipo_de_variable):
    if numero > 10:
       # Haz una serie de cosas y finalmente...
       return "Hola"

    # Si no, devuelve o bien una cadena vacía o bien una lista vacía
    # dependiendo de lo que diga `tipo_de_variable`
    return tipo_de_variable() # con esto instancias la clase
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Efectivamente mi ejemplo es muy limitado y no transmite lo que quiero hacer. Esencialmente, esta función es una a llamar en distintos puntos y que sirve para parsear un texto. Si se cumplen unas casuísticas, hago una extracción; si no, devuelvo un valor vacío que puede ser `''` o `[]`.